# Unistalling dual boot ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall

I recently bought ***DELL Inspiron 7547*** that came with Windows 8.1. I then decided to use Linux(dual boot) and installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (what a mistake!). After few days, **grub** failed to show Windows on the list of OSs. Since I haven't created the Windows recovery CD, I am stuck.

I have even tried to reinstall Ubuntu(the same version and 12.01) but now the bios doesn't show me the option of booting from USB. So, there is little that I can do.

Long story short, how do I get back to my Windows and remove Ubuntu with all its *grab* and what not from my machine?

P.S- I have searched for similar questions on this site and tried most of them for over a month now. But nothing works, and since my laptop doesn't accept CD, I install things using Bootable USB, CD based solutions won't help.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** (if this helps)

```
grep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep windows
```

returns nothing. If I just do  `grep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg` I see only Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're deleting Ubuntu, your best option is to download the [official Windows 8 CD/DVD from Microsoft](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271128), burn that to a CD/DVD and use the Windows 8 recovery options.  (That CD/DVD will recognize you have an OEM version without its recovery option created and act as a recovery CD/DVD)

Also, I'll be flagging your question for migrating to http://superuser.com where we have more people with more knowledge then me who will be able to help you further.

(I basically did the opposite of you: I deleted Windows 8 about a year ago and fully switched to Ubuntu since then)